# How to stick the element to the left if position sticky doesn't work?

Tags: css, sass, position, css-position, styling

I have a navbar that I want to position to the right when a media queries are meet:

**Navbar element**

```
.Navbar {
  @include display-flex(space-between, center, row);
  background-color: $semi-dark-blue;
  padding: 1.125rem;
  // media queries for laptops
  @include query(laptop) {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100vh;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    @include display-flex(space-between, center, column);
  }
}
```

**Parent element**

```
.App {
  background-color: $dark-blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 23.4375rem;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

**Parents parent element**

```
html {
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

I tried already to remove the overflow from parents elements as I found on the internet, but it doesn't work for me. Does anyone see the issue?

Answer (score 1):

```
 position: sticky;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
```

That is what is preventing your navbar from moving to the right.

Answer (score 1):

Position sticky will most probably not work if overflow is set to hidden, scroll, or auto on any of the parents of the element.

Comment: I tried to delete those properties from parents, but it doesn't make any changes.

Comment: Are you sure! you delete it from `html` and `.App` ?